# Want to hide not permitted admin menu in opencart. Using version opencart-2.0.2.0

Tags: opencart2.x

Using `opencart-2.0.2.0`, I want to hide not permitted menu items from admin form. 
Already tried the `vqmodhidemenuadmin` extension.

Is there any other vqmod code that I can write to get the required behavior?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change following code in `/admin/view/template/common/menu.tpl`:

```
<li><a href="<?php echo $category; ?>"><?php echo $text_category; ?></a></li>
```

To this:

```
<? if ($this->user->hasPermission('access', 'catalog/category')) { ?>
   <li><a href="<?php echo $category; ?>"><?php echo $text_category; ?></a></li>
<? } ?>
```

Change `catalog/category` according the line/link you want to hide.

Comment: Hi, I tried to hid my other menus by turning them into a comment but nothing happens